# Using GLSL to determine 3D position from mouse click

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl

I was wondering about the problem of getting 3D position from a 2D one.  In my application, I got everything set up (mvp matrix, screen position of mouse).

We go from 3D to 2D by the following transform.

gl_Position = projection* view * model * vertex;

Then these clip coordinates are divided by w to NDC, and then converted to screen coordinates.  I want to do the reverse (mouse click to 3D).  Screen to NDC is easy for x and y.  But there is a loss of z data.

As far as I can tell, the ONLY method to recover the 3D data is using ray-casting with a tree based spatial data structure and maybe CUDA/OpenCL.  But I am not sure.  Is there any other way?  Is there a method to recover 3D position given that we have the MVP matrix and screen coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the deph value at the mouse pointer position (glReadPixels(…, GL_DEPTH,…)) and use that for recovering Z. Or do the raycasting into a scene structure. Depending on your applications either one may be the better solution.

Comment: As as I can tell, glReadPixels returns color data (RGBA) not 3D data (x,y,z).  Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @TringVu: glReadPixels returns *framebuffer* data. And for depth testing there's a "depth buffer" (GL_DEPTH) that holds a value monotonic to the distance from the origin (it's not linear for perspective projection). That, together with the window position gives you a 3-vector that can be back-projected through the inverse transformation pipeline.

Comment: @TringVu: Note that what you're asking for is actually a FAQ under the subject called "picking":. Google for "OpenGL picking glReadPixels GL_DEPTH" and you'll find plenty of results.